# ListView Adapter OnTouchListener always detected at the same item in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and when an item is touched, it should change that item.

I have the following code to achieve that:

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {

    // 1. Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

    FrameLayout clickableItem = (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.clickLayout);
    ChangeColor(rowView);

    final View finalRow=rowView;

    clickableItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
      {
        ChangeColor(finalRow);
        Log.w("DEBUG","clicked item "+view.getId());
        return false;
      }
    });

    return rowView;
  }

  private void ChangeColor(View rowView)
  {
    FrameLayout clickItem= (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.clickLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)         clickItem.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, layoutParams.rightMargin == -160 ? 0 : -160, 0);
    clickItem.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  }
```

As you can see, I don't use convertView, so every item is a new object.
When I click any item, my first item changes. The log always shows the same ID.

What should I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not setting the id of the view by calling view.setId(). For that reason, you are getting the id value specified for the view in your xml file.

Comment: The id is not relevant. The problem is that _clickableItem_ is always the same. There should be as many instances as many _rowView_ views are visible (average is 5).

Comment: Can you post ChangeColor, please?